# Symfony join the same table to get the value as aliase from table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
id  name   referred_by_id
1   test1  2
2   test2  1
3   test3  1
```

I want to add a new column for query out put referredByName based on referredByID. which is equal to id.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name AS refname 
FROM tbl_students t1 
JOIN tbl_students t2 
   ON t1.referred_by_id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

i want to do this JOIN(same table) in Symsofny for my Query

```
   $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('C2EducateToolsBundle:Students');
            $leadsData['leads'] = $repo->createQueryBuilder('t')
                            ->select('t.id', 't.name','t.referredByID','t.referredBy')
                            ->where('t.id = :stuID')
                            ->setParameter('stuID', $leadId)
                            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

do i have to changes any associaltion in entity.?

i Changed my Entity

```
 /**
             * @var integer $referredByID
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="referred_by_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
             * @Type("integer")
             */
            protected $referredByID;
```

To

```
/**
     * @var referredByID
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Students", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="referred_by_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Type("C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Entity\Students")
     */
    protected $referredByID;
```

Comment: Yes you have to define referredBy property as (many to one & one to many) in your student entity as self referencing entity. So that when you get student object it will also have  referredBy object of student type

Comment: I did that, i update the same in my question. how can I get that field in my doctrine Query.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an association mapping in your main entity then you don't need to mention in query builder because when you get the doctrine object it will have the data of its associated objects like in your query update select method to `->select('t')`.

If your query returns student object against the provided student id then on student object you can call the getter method of its associated object as

```
$student->getReferredByID()->getName()
```

Above statement will return the name of associated student who is marked as referred by for this object.

Also if you are searching through primary key you can just use the `find()` method on repository instead of using query builder.

Although you can give aliases in query builder also

Comment: Yes it looks fine to me but name convention is not as per standard, Like when define any association you define the relation name like `$referredBy` instead of `$referredByID`

Answer (score 0):

After you have association defined in entity, Your query should be something like this :

```
    $repo->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.id', 't.name','t.referredByID', 'p.name as parent_name')
        ->join('t.referredByID', 'p') // joining self entity with parent id ref.
        ->where('t.id = :stuID')
        ->setParameter('stuID', $leadId)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This should get you relevant parent name under `parent_name` key.

But, Since the query seems to be for a single entry. Why don't you simply load the entity and use getter ref to load parent entity and name?

Comment: i am getting this error. `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 496 near 'referredByID,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

Comment: Just check with the property Name. rest should be same.